# Cooking with beer for a vegetarian

Tags: cooking

I know, that there are many threads on what you can cook with beer as an ingredient.

*But: I recognized that all of them include some sort of meat or fish and I eat neither.*

So what am I asking you:

Do you have some ideas on how to use the possibly greatest liquid of all times to cook some awesome (vegetarian or vegan) dishes?

To start I think I found a nice beer-pumpkin soup which ingredients are, besides the obvious beer and pumpkin, butter, onions, vinegar, cream and cress.

**EDIT :**

To be more clear. I ask you to name me something that you have tried and that you would recommend.

Comment: This may help:http://www.feastie.com/recipes-diet/vegetarian/ingredients/beer-7596

Comment: By adding the "you've tried and recommend" you make this opinion based and should be closed.

Comment: Or a CW at best, since there is no one right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great recipe that use lots of beer:

Vegetarian Pot Pie:
2 Bottles of Stout
Carrots, celery, onion, garlic, oil or butter, potatos (pre-baked for 30min)
salt and pepper to taste
2 pie shells 
1 bag of white flower

Pre-heat oven to 400 degrees

Brown the vegetables in a skillet over medium heat.
Add salt and sugar to get the caramelization going. 
Pour in the beer and bring to a boil.
Slowly pour in and stir the white flour, 1 cup at a time, until it becomes very gloopy.
Keep at a low simmer / boil.

Fill the pie shell with the gloopy stew, and cover the top with the 2nd pie shell.

Bake in the oven for 50 minutes. Then take it out and let it cool for a few minutes before serving.

Comment: 1 bag of flower or flour perhaps? :) one bag = 1kg?

Answer (score 3):

I used this recipe for [Black Bean Soup with Roasted Poblano Chiles](http://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/black-bean-soup-with-roasted-poblano-chiles).  It doesn't include beer as an ingredient but I chose this recipe as part of the beer/food pairing menu I put together for my parents.  I decided to pair it with Out of the Ashes (Smoked Marzen) from Fort Collins Brewery.  I poured about 1 1/2 cups of it into the soup while it was cooking.  You may not be a fan of smoked beers, but it went amazing with this soup.  The smokiness blended with the soup and did not have a strong flavor.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment yet, I need to use this answer box...

I guess you could just create the exact same dish and leave out the meat or replace it by those vegetarian replacements (quorn etc.).
I can imagine a beer stew would be epic without the meat but with more vegetables.

I quickly looked up one of our Belgian dishes in a vegetarian way, more specific: stoverij

Stoverij translated would be "stewed things" or something like that.

[Here](http://www.standaard.be/cnt/dmf20130316_041) is the original recipe (in Dutch).
Try to translate it through Google translate. If you have troubles, I could help I guess.

The old tradition is to use a sandwich with mustard and high quality beer, you'll read that :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am _not_ looking for regular dishes where you just leave the meat. A vegetarian dish is no collection of side-dishes (imho). I'm also not a great fan of "meat substitutes" like tofu to make a vegan schnitzel. (but I like your link)

Answer (score 2):

I made beer bagels several years ago, and the beer imparted a sort of sour dough flavor.

Guinness ice cream was also delightful - http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/emeril-lagasse/guinness-ice-cream-with-dark-chocolate-honey-sauce-recipe.html

Beer batter onion rings also come out nicely, but I've never really tasted the beer after frying. That being said, if you are up for frying, anything that asks for a seltzer in the batter for the bubbles could probably sub in a brew.

Answer (score 1):

In my country drink made of mulled beer (usually with some spices) mixed with egg yolks beaten with sugar is quite popular. It is kind of thing you prepare when you are ill. As dessert it is considered "controversial") But you can try, some people really like it.

Maybe I should add that it is rather hard to make, because you need right temperature of a liquid, so that mixture thickens but yolks do not coagulate.

Answer (score 1):

Stone Brewery serves a [smokey cheddar garlic soup](http://www.stoneworldbistro.com/bistro_menus/dinner.asp) at their tasting room bistro which is cooked with their Ruination IPA. The bitterness balances the salt and richness of the cheddar. I would definitely use IPA cautiously in cooking though, as the beer and alcohol will partially evaporate, causing the hop bitterness to concentrate noticably.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a step back and remember that beer may include isinglass as fining as per this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarianism_and_beer.

Going back to your question of dishes with beer that I tried, adding some beer to a crepe is good to make it taste richer.

Crepe recipe is really easy. Mix the following in a blender: 1 glass of milk, 1 egg, 1 glass of wheat flour, some oil, some beer, a bit of salt and a bit of sugar. Use a fry-pan to bake the crepes. Tomato, cheese and herbs are my favorite topping for crepes.

Good luck.

Comment: Good point to check the production process. I never thought, that they may use anything else than hops, barley malt, water and yeast..